# create treeview node based on url structure .net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, treeview

am trying to pupulate a treeview nodes base on directory structure like this

```
Dim arrLinks() As String = Split(Url, "/")

For i As Integer = 0 To arrLinks.Length
    If tvwDirs.Nodes.ContainsKey(arrLinks(0)) = False Then
        tvwDirs.Nodes.Add(arrLinks(0), arrLinks(0))
    End If
Next
```

The above code works for add base/parent node

say i have a urllike this `example.com/dir1/dir2/file`

in this case, it should create a child node dir2 in parent node dir1

am getting confused add child nodes to the existing nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue you are going to run into is an exception based on your for statement; you should either change it to:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To arrLinks.Length - 1
```

or, my preference:

```
For each nodeKey as String in arrLinks
```

The next issue is that the Nodes collection does not contain all of the Nodes in the entire tree, it only contains the top level nodes. Each node in this list has its own set of child nodes and each of those children has child nodes, etc.

This means that as you add each node, you need to keep track of the last parent node and add the next child to that parent node or keep track of the current collection of nodes for the level that you are adding to.

This will result in code similar to the following (you may need to adjust the class names for NodeCollection and Node and possible the Add statement (don't remember off the top if add returns a Node or not)):

```
Dim arrLinks() As String = Split(Url, "/")
Dim cNodes as NodeCollection

' Keep track of the current collection of nodes, starting with the tree's top level collection
cNodes = tvwDirs.Nodes

For each nodeKey As String in arrLinks
    Dim currentNode as Node

    If Not cNodes.ContainsKey(nodeKey) Then
        ' If the key is not in the current collection of nodes, add it and record the resultant record
        currentNode = cNodes.Add(nodeKey, nodeKey)
    Else
        ' Otherwise, record the current node
        currentNode = cNodes(nodeKey)
    End If
    ' Store the set of nodes that the next nodeKey will be added to
    cNodes = currentNode.Nodes
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for your help i need to add image to the tree view based on the node level, any node with child node would be folder, and without file/ thanks

Answer (score 0):

Untested, may contain syntax or spelling errors:

```
Sub MakeTreeNodes
  Dim tURI As Uri = New Uri("proto://domain.tld/dir1/dir2/dir3")
  Dim tNode as TreeNode = New TreeNode(tURI.DnsSafeHost)

  If 1 < tURI.Segments.Length
    CreateNode(tURI.Segments, 1, tNode)
  End If

  SomeTreeView.Nodex.Add(tNode)

End Sub


Private Sub CreateNode(byval tSegments() As String, ByVal tIndex As Int16, ByRef tParentNode As TreeNode) As TreeNode

  Dim tNode As TreeNode = New TreeNode(tSegments(tIndex))

  If (tSegments.Length - 1) < tIndex
    CreateNode(tSegments, tIndex + 1, tNode)
  End If

  tParentNode.Nodes.Add(tNode)

End Function
```

Brief explanation:
MakeTreeNodes() is the entry point.  I would suggest modifying it to accept a string URL, as well as possibly an overload for a URI.
It creates a root node with the host anme of the URI.

Then it calls the recursive function CreateNode().  This creates a new TreeNode with the current segment, and then calls itsself passing the newly created node and the next index value.
It's pretty standard faire for a recursive function.

Comment: thanks, but i get alot of erros, and can't fix it as i dony understand you algorithim

Comment: it was adding the base url as each parent node, and then adding the directories under each parent node. It was supose to add a parent node, which is the host e.g `www.example.com`, then add the first directories as child node of the host, and so on